# c# regex - alternative text

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get the familyId and there is an alternative between compar/produ.aspx. I use the regex:

\/selector/**(compar.+|produ.+)**.aspx\?famiid=**(\d{2})**\&produ=\d{2}

that matches:
/selector/comparioPage.aspx?famiid=32&produ=40
and
/selector/productCust.aspx?famiid=32&produ=40

and I get the **familyId** as the second match.

Actually I have to use () to make the alternative possible (compar or produ). The problem is I do not want to get compario or product in the match groups.

However if I remove the (), the regex behaves differently: /selector/ is not part of the selection :(

How can I get rid of () and get only the familyId?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a [non-capturing group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) by using this syntax: `(?:...)`

So your pattern becomes `(?:compar.+|produ.+)`

It's not clear why you didn't use the full name of the pages, unless other pages exist with the same prefix. If so a better pattern might be:

```
@"/selector/(?:compar|produ)[^.]+\.aspx\?famiid=(\d+)&produ=\d+";
```

By using `[^.]+` it will match everything except a period. Also, why limit the digits to two? What if there's one or more? `\d+` is more flexible unless you intended to limit it to IDs of length 2.

Comment: mark this as answer; mine was interesting but I didn't know bout the ?: trick.

Comment: @Paul your generosity is appreciated. Glad you found it useful. I upvoted your response since it's a useful strategy to single out particular groups as well.

Comment: you are right, the pattern must match pages prefixed by compar- such as compario.asp, comparioCust.apsx, etc

Answer (score 2):

Why get rid of them?  Just take the second match group, or else you can use a named match group like so:

```
\/selector/(?<pageName>compar.+|produ.+).aspx\?famiid=(?<familyId>\d{2})\&produ=\d{2}
```

The match groups returned can be accessed by name like groups["familyId"]

Comment: Actualy I only need one match group for generic reason.

Comment: I understand you only need one; my point is that you're not hurting anything by having more than one and only using the one you need.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I have learnt two different things by asking only one question :p